# Counting for possibilities of passwords containing at least one uppercase letter, one lowercase letter, and one digit

Tags: combinatorics, solution-verification

How many $8$ character passwords are there if each character is either an uppercase letter A-Z, a lower case letter a-z, or a digit 0-9,  and where at least one character of each of the three types is used?

So there are $26 \cdot 26 \cdot 10$ for the Uppercase, lowercase, and digit. Then we have $\binom{8}{3}$ ways to put them in the password. $\binom{8}{3} = 56$. Then the rest of the $5$ character slots can be anything. So $26+26+10 = 62$. So we have $62^5$. 
So wouldn't the answer just be $26^2 \cdot 10 \cdot 56 \cdot 62^5$?

Comment: Your calculation is hard to follow.  What does "So there are 26⋅26⋅10 for the Uppercase, lowercase, and digit." mean?  More significantly:  you can't place the "one of each type" first and then toss the others in randomly without overcounting badly.  Easier to do it by inclusion-exclusion.

Comment: Okay. Sorry but I'm not sure how to fix my mistake. Can you explain? Also, for the 10*26*26, I meant it for the one of each type. So there are 26 possible for upper then lower then 10 possible for the digit.

Comment: But then why write it as a product?  That's just confusing.  As to the more fundamental error, you can't "pre-choose" the one-of-each-type.  Say your password was $Aa1AAAAA$.  Which of those six $A's$ was the pre-chosen one?  Indeed, you'll count this at least $6$ times, one for each $A$.  But inclusion-exclusion works well for this sort of problem.  Give that a try.

Comment: Oh okay. I didn't see the "at least" part. Sorry I really didn't know what I was doing. Thanks though.

Comment: Yes, that "at least" should not be there (it belonged to a different sort of example which I ended up discarding).  Your method would count $Aa1AAAAA$ exactly six times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are counting each password multiple times, once each for the number of uppercase letters, lowercase letters, and digits that appear in the password.

There are $26 + 26 + 10 = 62$ ways each of the eight positions could be filled, so there are $62^8$ possible passwords.  From these, we must subtract those in which there are no uppercase letters, no lowercase letters, or no digits.

Let $P$ be the set of all passwords.  Let $U$, $L$, and $D$ be, respectively, the set of passwords that contain an uppercase letter, a lowercase letter, or a digit.  Then we wish to find 
$$|U \cap L \cap D| = |P| - |U' \cup L' \cup D'|$$
By the [Inclusion-Exclusion Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle),

$$|U' \cup L' \cup D'| = |U'| + |L'| + |D'| - |U' \cap L'| - |U' \cap D'| - |L' \cap D'| + |U' \cap L' \cap D'|$$

$|U'|$:  $U'$ is the set of passwords that do not contain uppercase letters.  That leaves $62 - 26 = 36$ characters we can use to fill each of the eight positions in the password.  Hence, $|U'| = 36^8$.

$|L'|$:  $L'$ is the set of passwords that do not contain lowercase letters.  Hence, $|L'| = 36^8$.

$|D'|$:  $D'$ is the set of passwords that do not contain digits.  That leaves $62 - 10 = 52$ characters we can use to fill each of the eight positions in the password, so $|D'| = 52^8$.

$|U' \cap L'|$:  $U' \cap L'$ is the set of passwords that contain neither uppercase nor lowercase letters.  That means each position in the password must be filled with one of the ten digits, so $|U' \cap L'| = 10^8$.

$|U' \cap D'|$:  $U' \cap D'$ is the set of passwords that contain neither uppercase letters nor digits.  That means each position in the password must be filled with one of the $26$ lowercase letters, so $|U' \cap D'| = 26^8$.

$|L' \cap D'|$:  $L' \cap D'$ is the set of passwords that contain neither lowercase letters nor digits.  That means each position in the password must be filled with one of the $26$ uppercase letters, so $|L' \cap D'| = 26^8$.

$|U' \cap L' \cap D'|$:  $U' \cap L' \cap D'$ is the set of passwords that contain no uppercase letters, no lowercase letters, and no digits, which is impossible, so $|U' \cap L' \cap D'| = 0$.