# Password creation combinatorics?

Tags: combinatorics

Suppose this set of rules for password creation, what is the exact or estimate size of the sample space ? ( Total number of legal passwords based on rule set )

Rule $1$) Character set : Upper and lowercase alphabets, numbers, @, #, $, &, -, +, *, ~.

Rule $2$) Length of password must be between $6$ and $12$ (inclusive).

Rule $3$) Adjacent numbers cannot be increasing or decreasing by $1$ and adjacent characters cannot be the same.

Rule $4$) Must contain at least $1$ upper and $1$ lower case alphabet, $2$ numbers, $1$ special character.

Rule $5$) Password cannot be a mirror pattern of $4$ characters.

- Acceptable : F24d#t7 , Eot3Eot#1
- Not acceptable : E0t#E0t#E0t# , a91BF@H4F@H4

Rule $6$) There must not be more than $3$ numbers in a row.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What kind of description of your sample space are you looking for?

Comment: Number of legal password that follows the rules, either an estimate or an exact value. So, the total number of password in the sample space.

Comment: Then please edit your question to specify you are looking for an estimate of the size of the sample space.

Comment: You better modify the opening line in your question to reflect this.

Comment: Done. The thing has been edited.

Answer (score 3):

Your alphabet $A$ is the disjoint union of four sets: $U$ (upper case letters), $L$ (lower case letters), $D$ (digits) and $S$ (symbols). One has $|U| = |L| = 26$, $|D| = 10$ and $|S| = 8$, and thus $|A| = 26 + 26 + 10 + 8 = 70$.

Rule 2 gives you a first upper bound
$$
70^6 + \dotsm + 70^{12} = \frac{70^{13}-70^6}{70-1}
$$
If you want to improve this upper bound, say by using Rule 4, you can use the method explained in this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3493738).

Comment: How about other rules such as 6 ?